# Do iOS sandbox Game Center Leaderboards carry over to real Game Center?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have successfully implemented Game Center leaderboards in my app and tested using iOS Simulator. After submitting the new version to iTunes Connect, will the sandbox scores translate over to the real Game Center? I used two real apple ID while testing.

I would prefer the scores to be blank on the real game center and not carry over from sandbox since they are pretty high as a result of testing errors.

Answer (score 2):

*If you have used live A/C for testing then it will surely reflect in Game Center leader-board.*

---

**Important:**

Always create new test accounts to test your game in Game Center. Never use an existing Apple ID.

It is mentioned in Apple docs:- https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/GameKit_Guide/TestingYourGameCenter-AwareGame/TestingYourGameCenter-AwareGame.html